# Simple regex replace regardless of middle text php

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

say I have this

```
searchpage-20/11111111111?node=15
```

how would I setup a regex to replace the entire string without worrying about the

```
11111111111
```

in the middle as long as the rest matches.

I tried

```
searchallmp3-20/(.+?)\?node=
```

Comment: With what do you want it to be replaced? And what have you tried till now?

Comment: i'm looking to replace the entire string when the front and end match but the middle (aka the ones 11111111..) in this case does not matter. I tried searchallmp3-20/(.+?)\?node= but it didn't work

Comment: `searchallmp3 != searchpage`.

Comment: yeah my bad I had changed it in the question to make it more basic

Comment: @Belgin.. I think you didn't understand both of my comments. First you need to tell with what do you want your text to be replaced with. I know you want to replace. But what would you like to add instead of your original text? Do you want to simply remove it? And again, you have given two examples - `searchpage..` and `searchallmp3`. So, your content of first part is not same. Which one to match?

Comment: sorry for being unclear I'm trying to simply remove it, also either one since i can just change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post the code, to see how you are calling the regex and you need also to describe, what is not working.

I assume you are getting some error message because you are using `/` without escaping it in your regex and your delimiter is also the `/`

Two possibilities:

1. Escape the `/`

   ```
   /searchallmp3-20\/(.+?)\?node=/
   ```
2. Use another delimiter

   ```
   ~searchallmp3-20/(.+?)\?node=~
   ```

See [Delimiters on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

I still don't get the replace part of your question. If you want to remove the digits before the `?`, you should capture the **other** parts of the string

```
 ~(searchallmp3-20/).+?(\?node=~)
```

and replace with

```
`$1$2`
```

this will result in

```
searchpage-20/?node=15
```

Is it this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
<?php
$search = 'searchpage-20/11111111111?node=15';
$reg = '#(searchpage-\d+/)\d+(\?node=\d+)#';
echo preg_replace($reg, '${1}blah${2}', $search);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
searchpage-20/blah?node=15
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this:

```
/searchpage-(\d+)\/(\d+)\?node=(\d+)/
```

Example usage:

```
preg_replace('/searchpage-(\d+)\/(\d+)\?node=(\d+)/', '', 'searchpage-20/11111111111?node=15');
```